# How to trigger packages to build automatically when using pnpm install?

Tags: typescript, monorepo, pnpm, pnpm-workspace

Our project use pnpm + workspace + typescript follow the monorepo standard. After clone the repository, we run pnpm install to install dependencies and link local packages to each other. But the code inside each package are still remain source code mode in the `.ts` files. How to trigger each package to run `pnpm run build` automatically in order to have a `dist` folder inside package when using `pnpm install` at the first time.

Answer (score 1):

add `prepare` script in each package.json,
like
`prepare: pnpm run build`.it will be triggered on local pnpm install without any arguments.